# IIS - Accept a HTTP GET, then wait, trigger POST to API, wait for POST 200 OK reply with REDIRECT to original HTTP GET

Tags: http, iis, http-post

I'd like to know if how I might achieve the following in IIS.

1. User clicks button in email with HTTP GET link.
2. Request is sent to IIS
3. IIS sends POST to MS Flow HTTP endpoint to trigger flow.
4. Flow finishes and sends back 200 OK
5. Original HTTP GET receives reply with REDIRECT to different URL (HTTP GET)

Essentially I need the first HTTP GET to tigger my flow, wait for it to complete then redirect the user to another webpage if successful.

Thanks !

Comment: IIS won't do that for you. You need a web framework (ASP.NET Core/NodeJS for example).

Comment: It is easily to achieve this with an api callback. The API will post request to your endpoint and return redirect flag after receiving 200 status. IIS itself don't process any call back logic.